# How to extract tags from html, json?

Tags: python, html, json

I have a json file that I need to extract certain html tags from a json file.

I have a hint below...`

[image]

Comment: can you post an example code

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```py
try:
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#example of json data (dictionary)
data = {
    "url":"www.example.com",
    "content" : "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><strong>My first paragraph.</strong></body></html>"
}

#html parser
soup = BeautifulSoup(data["content"], "html.parser")

#get all the tags of one type
print(soup.find_all("h1"))
print(soup.find_all("strong"))
```

And you will get a list of tags like:

```
[<h1>My First Heading</h1>]
[<strong>My first paragraph.</strong>]
```

To install bs4:

```sh
pip install bs4
```

I hope it helps